# The Web of Puzzles

Tags: riddle, rhyme, acrostic

> Looking for an exit? You won't escape that easily,
> Overwhelmed with hexes, I'll make you shift uneasily,
>
> So many questions, but so little time,
> Too few suggestions, forbidden to climb.
>
> Perhaps you follow the old adage, to have one hand always on me.
> A foolish attempt, useless baggage, you can never trust what you see.
>
> Take heed to be well prepared, or else I'll kill you when we meet.
> Hear my warnings and be scared, constant change my dominant feat.

What am I?

Hint:

> You come to me in groups, with lust in your hearts,
>  You must defeat my troops, using your various arts.

Hint 2: (Since the newer answers are going away from what I had in mind)

> Gather together at the local place, there you'll learn about my dangers,
>  My troops are armed with sword, spear, axe, and mace. Can you defeat all my rangers?

Comment: Small question: is it supposed to be 'to few' in stead of 'too few'? Non-native speaker here, so I'm not sure. Looking at all these puzzles has made me doubt myself more than once..

Comment: @FlorisSA, you're right, my mistake. I've modified it to fix that typo.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know, hint, I really want to know the answer now! :D +1

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie, I added a hint.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Are you looking for a fully interpreted answer for this? It would appear you've noted an answer as correct via comments but it hasn't been accepted? What are the requirements for acceptance on this one? Great puzzle by the way!

Comment: @PerpetualJ, That answer will be accepted. I always wait 24 hours before accepting, though.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Oh yeah, I forgot about that part! HAHA Again, great puzzle!

Comment: Yeah, I can’t think of many words that rhyme with “easily” apart from “*un*easily”, hahah. Beautiful riddle (as always) nonetheless! Right now, I am on a **lost path** in trying to find the answer without looking at the answers posted below! DVL22 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it perhaps

> A Dungeons and Dragons dungeon ?

Looking for an exit? You won't escape that easily,

> Filled with traps, some doors will require keys from treasure chests

Overwhelmed with hexes, I'll make you shift uneasily,

> Besides traps, some enemies may cast hexes on you affecting your abilities

So many questions, but so little time,

> Typically, a game is played when players ask questions of a Dungeon Master(DM)

Too few suggestions, forbidden to climb.

> Not too sure here, a DM typically doesn't make suggestion to players and you can't really climb out of a dungeon (usually)

Perhaps you follow the old adage, to have one hand always on me.

> Again, not sure what adage applies here, but in a dungeon I would keep a hand on my weapon/wand as you don't know what will creep up on you

A foolish attempt, useless baggage, you can never trust what you see.

> Illusions are a big part of the game, so you can't truly be sure what you are looking at if it's an enemy or just the illusion of one

Take heed to be well prepared, or else I'll kill you when we meet.

> Some campaigns are long and will require supplies and some characters need ingredients for spells, etc.

Hear my warnings and be scared, constant change my dominant feat.

> Some game playing sessions last weeks or longer as this is an evolving story narrated by the Dungeon Master

Secret Hints
Hint 1
You come to me in groups, with lust in your hearts,

> Dungeons and Dragons is played in groups, adventurers who have the objective of growth, seeking treasure or other motives

You must defeat my troops, using your various arts.

> It is a collaborative game, each party member usually filling a different role in the strategy of the game

Hint 2
Gather together at the local place, there you'll learn about my dangers,

> Most campaigns start a local pub where players hear about local rumors that start the adventure

My troops are armed with sword, spear, axe, and mace. Can you defeat all my rangers?

> Common weapons used in the game, ranger is one of the "classes" in the game

As with any great Joe-You-Know puzzle, there is an acrostic on the beginning of each line,

> LOST PATH This is a reference to Pathfinder as well, one of the "flavors" of table top Role-Playing Games
>  The second acrostic is GM, found in the second hint, which stands for Game Master, I believe, the equivalent to a Dungeon Master in this RPG

Comment: This is it! There are a couple hidden clues I've thrown in. Can you find them?

Comment: Though, I would have simply taken rot13(Qhatrba) as the answer. I was thinking about this specific variety when constructing the puzzle, but any kind would have worked.

Comment: There are two acrostic clues in the puzzle. Can you add them in?

Comment: I'll keep looking for the clues, I have added a response to the second hint.  Really great Puzzle, @Joe-You-Know

Comment: Interesting interpretation of that acrostic. I was thinking more of rot13(Cngusvaqre), but this works too.

Comment: P.S. The second acrostic is found in the second hint.

Comment: A-ha!  I was thinking it was an acrostic with both Hints, but that make a lot more sense

Answer (score 5):

are you -

> Lost Path, that is what the acrostic says

---

New guess

> Map maybe, when you lose path, you take its help to find it

---

Third Guess

> A board game with maps maybe, guessing Risk.

---

Final guess:

> shot in the dark, but could it be Dungeons and Dragons

Comment: No, but it is an additional clue to what I am.

Comment: It's not this either.

Comment: Whoa I never thought of that! +1

Comment: The third answer isn't quite right either.

Comment: oh well, worth a shot i guess..

Comment: The answer is not a game, but part of one. Your final answer is closest yet! Stay on target!

Answer (score 5):

Are you a

> Pacman?

Looking for an exit? You won't escape that easily,
Overwhelmed with hexes, I'll make you shift uneasily,

> You can't escape and ghosts chase you.

So many questions, but so little time,
To few suggestions, forbidden to climb.

> You run around the maze.

Perhaps you follow the old adage, to have one hand always on me.
A foolish attempt, useless baggage, you can never trust what you see.

> The old machine is what classic-ers would have.

Take heed to be well prepared, or else I'll kill you when we meet.
Hear my warnings and be scared, constant change my dominant feat.

> If you run into the ghosts, well you lose a life.

Hidden Hint

> LOST PATH.

Comment: Not quite, but this is an excellent guess.

Comment: no, I wouldn't be that specific about the answer.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie looks like we're looking for something similar to yours but not as specific as mine...

Comment: That's what I was thinking, although I'm sure he'd have put a knowledge or movies tag if that were the case

Comment: Hmm, yeah good thinking :)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I like to attribute my tags. No trivia or knowledge tag is needed this time. I would suggest not taking things so literally? As in, maybe this all is just a game? :-)

Comment: Ooh I like this answer, @QuantumTwinkie!! +1

Comment: I like this answer too! I'd recommend leaving this answer here, and submitting a different answer when the time comes. Because this is still wrong. Notice, I don't have the video game tag either. It's not a movie, or a video game.

Comment: Psst, The acrostic is more important than you think. Here's a question for you, what do you do when you lose something?

Comment: I mean yes, but you rot13(svaq vg!)

Answer (score 4):

Is this

> a Labyrinth?

Looking for an exit? You won't escape that easily,

> It was said to be impossible to escape from, even Daedalus had trouble doing so after he created it. Labyrinths are difficult in general.

Overwhelmed with hexes, I'll make you shift uneasily,

> There are quite a few crafty shifts and mechanical "hexes" which were added to the maze.

So many questions, but so little time,

> There are lots of choices/lots of paths to take.

Too few suggestions, forbidden to climb.

> You can't climb out of a labyrinth, and you do them alone.

Perhaps you follow the old adage, to have one hand always on me.

> This could be the right-hand rule or left-hand rule to solving mazes.

A foolish attempt, useless baggage, you can never trust what you see.

> This probably doesn't help in a real labyrinth.

Take heed to be well prepared, or else I'll kill you when we meet.

> A possible Minotaur reference? Thank goodness Theseus was prepared.

Hear my warnings and be scared, constant change my dominant feat.

> The labyrinth could mechanically keep changing its pathways; and you could hear the Minotaur in it.

Comment: Not quite, though I would say this is the closest answer yet. (This answer may be a little **too** specific). This answer may or may not qualify for the answer I'm looking for. (Honestly, different people would argue either way if it is or not)

Comment: @Joe-You-Know So if I made it more general than the specific one I mentioned, is it still too specific?

Comment: Honestly, rot13(V qba'g guvax nalbar jbhyq nethr gung Qnrqnyhf'f Ynolevagu jnfa'g n ynolevagu.) The answer is the right specificity now, but it's not quite what I had in mind. "I'll kill you when we meet" is especially important here.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know, that's a good point, fair enough.

Comment: You almost make it sound like the TV show Crystal maze!!!

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by the previous answers, my guess is that you are you maybe:

> The maze from Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire?

Looking for an exit? You won't escape that easily,

> It was hard to get out of the maze

Overwhelmed with hexes, I'll make you shift uneasily,

> Main reason for my answer. When I looked up 'hexes' (non-native speaker as I am), I encountered a lot of Harry Potter references

So many questions, but so little time,

> In the story, they are racing eachother in the maze, to be the one to complete it within the shortest timespan

Too few suggestions, forbidden to climb.

> Climbing over the walls is not possible/allowed (I think the maze was actually covered with ivy in the books if I remember correctly)

Perhaps you follow the old adage, to have one hand always on me.

> A trick to finding the exit in a maze is to stay in contact with one of the walls (either the right or left)

A foolish attempt, useless baggage, you can never trust what you see.

> After reaching the Goblet in the centre, they trust it and grab it, but it turns out to be a portkey

Take heed to be well prepared, or else I'll kill you when we meet.

> Which leads them to the one who shall not be named..

Hear my warnings and be scared, constant change my dominant feat.

> Not sure about this one (the maze doesn't change itself as far as I know), but they were scared alright!

Edit: ah heck, I just saw that you mentioned it is not a movie :-(

Comment: This is an excellent answer, but not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be

> A Sandy Desert?

Looking for an exit? You won't escape that easily,

> It is very hard to find the exit to a desert as they keep going and going

Overwhelmed with hexes, I'll make you shift uneasily,

> hexes could be the sand which shifts as you walk

So many questions, but so little time,

> There are lots of choices/lots of paths to take.

Too few suggestions, forbidden to climb.

> every time you climb a sand dune you slide back down.

Perhaps you follow the old adage, to have one hand always on me.

> when climbing you climb with hands and feet for extra purchase???.

A foolish attempt, useless baggage, you can never trust what you see.

> Mirages mean you can't trust what you see

Take heed to be well prepared, or else I'll kill you when we meet.

> bring water or you'll die of dyhydration

Hear my warnings and be scared, constant change my dominant feat.

> sand dunes shift and move with the wind

Comment: This is a great answer! But it's not what I'm looking for. The secret clue plays a big part in this riddle.

Comment: Love this answer Blade Wraith, it goes down a completely different avenue!

Answer (score 1):

Could the answer to this be

> [a Maze-Searching Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm)?

Looking for an exit? You won't escape that easily,

> Many mazes can be difficult.

Overwhelmed with hexes, I'll make you shift uneasily,

> Sometimes the mazes can shift paths, that's what the algorithm will do.

So many questions, but so little time,

> Many paths to search, but the goal is to optimize the maze solver to minimize the time.

Too few suggestions, forbidden to climb.

> You can't climb out of the maze.

Perhaps you follow the old adage, to have one hand always on me.

> I still think this is the right-hand rule to solving mazes. This is the very basic Wall Follower algorithm.

A foolish attempt, useless baggage, you can never trust what you see.

> But there are faster algorithmic ways to solve the maze.

Take heed to be well prepared, or else I'll kill you when we meet.

> A reference to the *dead-end filling* algorithm?

Hear my warnings and be scared, constant change my dominant feat.

> The algorithm constantly changes direction to find the optimal (only) path.

The secret hint is

> LOST PATH, a reference to the algorithm finding the lost path in the maze.

Comment: Your previous answer was much, much closer. P.S. The secret hint is pretty important. It may or may not be referring to a non-video game.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> A Chess Champion?

Looking for an exit? You won't escape that easily,

> If you're in Checkmate or in trouble then its hard to escape without losing

Overwhelmed with hexes, I'll make you shift uneasily,

> Too many options to jump over or move around, you'll worry its the right move

So many questions, but so little time,

> There are lots of choices to make

Too few suggestions, forbidden to climb.

> Many options but the opposing player stops you climbing up the board to become king, or move a pawn to make it a queen

Perhaps you follow the old adage, to have one hand always on me.

> Keep your hand on your piece until you have made certain you are happy with the move

A foolish attempt, useless baggage, you can never trust what you see.

> If the other player moves you don't know if its to make you make a move or to an actual attack

Take heed to be well prepared, or else I'll kill you when we meet.

> make sure you pieces are covered or the opponent will take you piece

Hear my warnings and be scared, constant change my dominant feat.

> The game develops and it changes constantly

Hints

> Chess champions face large groups of opponants that lust after the glory of beating the champion, and you need to beat his "troops" pieces to beat him

Only problem is that it doesn't fit with the secret hint

> Hexadecimal dice???

Comment: This answer is awesome! It does fit really well, besides the hidden clue. You are on the right path with games though.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know So its a board game then? AAARGH this puzzle is annoying me now! i need to figure it out

Comment: @Joe-You-Know, edited check the lost box!

Comment: The answer isn't a game, but part of one [sort of] (it exists outside of games too, just not in the way I refer to it in the puzzle). The game it stems from isn't really a board game (at least, I don't think it is). I think it's description does call it this, but most people would argue it's an entirely different genre.

Comment: @joe-you-know perhaps my re edited final box... nothing I can come with matches you secret hint. I both love and hate you right now. In the nicest possible way of course

Answer (score 1):

Could you be

> A **GRIEVER** from the movie/book series, **The Maze Runner** (if you want to read the books or are a massive fan of the author, *James Dashner*, you can go [here](http://www.jamesdashner.com/the-maze-runner-series/)). 
>  <sub>**WARNING**: SPOILER ALERTS WILL FOLLOW.</sub>

`Looking for an exit? You won't escape that easily,`

> It is **very difficult** to escape the Maze.

`Overwhelmed with hexes, I'll make you shift uneasily,`

> Every night, the Maze **shifts** position with a periodic pattern every month (at least, that is what I remember from the book). Also, the word **hex** means to "cast a spell on; bewitch". The pattern **spells** out words like a secret code: FLOAT - CATCH - BLEED - DEATH - STIFF - PUSH ([here](http://mazerunner.wikia.com/wiki/The_Maze)).

`So many questions, but so little time,`

> When the first girl, **Teresa**, wakes up in the Box, she carries a note reading: *She is the last one. Ever.* Then supplies stop coming... and **time starts to run out**. Also, the Maze closes at night, and your time might run out if you get trapped inside!

`Too few suggestions, forbidden to climb.`

> It is all so puzzling! And you **cannot  climb** the walls of the Maze. (Book: it stretches high and tall forever, I believe. Movie: vines do not reach the top.)

`Perhaps you follow the old adage, to have one hand always on me.`

> Some of the **ol' fellas** that have remained in the Glade (and perhaps in the Maze; i.e., during the daytime) from the very beginning (and **not the Greenbeans**) have seen the grievers...

`A foolish attempt, useless baggage, you can never trust what you see.`

> You only see grievers when it's dark, and boy, you don't know *what* to expect when you are in the Maze... but of course, people need to carry "**baggage**" in order to defend themselves, particularly the **Runners**. There are also the **Keepers**, for which a guy by the name of Minho is the Keeper of the Runners... but there is also mention of a Keeper of the **Baggers** ([here](http://mazerunner.wikia.com/wiki/Keepers)).

`Take heed to be well prepared, or else I'll kill you when we meet.`

> That's what **grievers** are famous for (especially the taunting nightmares accompanied with their sting, ouch!). Thank God in the book, there is an antidote. (Not too sure about the movie.)

`Hear my warnings and be scared, constant change my dominant feat.`

> I guess that refers to the **stinger**!

`What am I?`

> A **GRIEVER**?

---

**Title:**

`The Web of Puzzles`

> Grievers look like giant **spiders**, and spiders make **webs**!

**Hint 1:**

`You come to me in groups, with lust in your hearts,`

> In the book, when the exit has *finally* been found, they are ready and prepared; they are **willing** to do whatever it takes to defeat the grievers, especially the **group** of them guarding the button in the exit!

`You must defeat my troops, using your various arts.`

> That includes **weapons and combat**.

**Hint 2:**

`Gather together at the local place, there you'll learn about my dangers,`

> That must refer to the **Glade** (or the **Homestead**, but I am going with the former option).

`My troops are armed with sword, spear, axe, and mace. Can you defeat all my rangers?`

> Grievers have all these kinds of similar weapons; they are unpredictable and very **mechanical**.

**Secret Clue:**

> The only thing you remember when you wake up in the Box is your name. I love how this riddle was made by **Joe-You-Know**, as he definitely knows *his* name :D

Answer (score 1):

My first post....

I'm 100% sure you are are you something related to:

> Software compiler, or some programming language or interpretter.

I just don't know what the correct taxonomy you are looking for would be. Two things are hard with

> software development. 
>  Naming things. 
>  Cache invalidation
>  Off by one errors...

I'm struggling with the naming things part!...

Anyway my reasoning is:

1

> exit = obvious keyword for an exit code.

2

> hexes+shift = compiler/machine code

3

> questions = logic

4

> climb = recursion

5

> one hand always on me = keyboard or WASD

6

> prepared = prepare statements + try/catch

7

> warnings = obvious error codes

8

> const = mutators/getter/setters.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (Puzzling.SE)**! Great answer! I see you are familiar with the Stack Exchange community as you are a member of Stack Overflow (and you have the +100 reputation bonus), so I think you'll get used to this site pretty quickly. I suggest you take a quick look some information in the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help), but I'm sure you'll be fine. Happy Puzzling! :D

Comment: Nice, I never thought of it like that. But, this is not the answer I'm looking for. Welcome to PSE though!